# Association has_many Rails Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, model-associations

I have three models, user, post and book, associated through a fourth, kms.

- Post model has many kms and books with through
- Book model has many kms and posts with through
- km belongs to book and post

I have tried [this tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised) for the above case and successful.

Now, I want to create an association stating that a Post.

- user has_many kms
- Km belongs to user

Associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tenantable::Schema::Model
  has_many :kms, dependent: :destroy

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me


end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :year, :author, :book_ids
  has_many :kms
  has_many :books, through: :kms   
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :kms
  has_many :posts, through: :kms
end

class Km < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :count, :book_id, :post_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here's create on PostsController looks like:

```
def create
  #this not working
  @post = current_user.build.kms(params[:post]) 
  @post.save
end
```

And here's on view form to create looks like:

```
<%= form_for @post, :url => create_post_subdomain_path(@post), :method => :post  do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :year, "Year" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :year %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :author, "Author" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :author %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Book" %><br />
    <%= hidden_field_tag "post[book_ids][]", nil %>
     <% Book.all.each_with_index do |book, index| %>
         <%= label_tag dom_id(book) do %>
          <%= check_box_tag "post[book_ids][]", book.id, @post.book_ids.include?(book.id), id: dom_id(book) %> <%= book.nama %>
          <% end %>&nbsp;
         <%= '<br/><br/>'.html_safe if index == 3 %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
    <br/>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit ( "Save" ), :class => "btn btn-inverse btn-medium" %>&nbsp;&nbsp; or &nbsp;&nbsp;<%= link_to 'Cancel', list_book_subdomain_path, :class => "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I try generate `current_user.id` to `km.user_id` when `user` create a `post`.

But I got the error

`Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name, year, author, book_ids`

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Your intention is unclear as currently written. What are you trying to do? Please rewrite what you want to happen. The rest makes sense.

Comment: I try generate `current_user` to `km` when `user` create a `post`, but not working, i got the error `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name, year, author, book_ids`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I found a solution, a solution like this :
`@post` create and update all column `user_id` on `km` where `@post_id => @post.id`, so the output will be like this

```
@post = Post.create(params[:post])
Km.where(:post_id => @post.id).update_all(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

**Output**

```
#<Km id: 1, post_id: 1, user_id: 1>,
#<Km id: 2, post_id: 1, user_id: 1>,
#<Km id: 3, post_id: 1, user_id: 1>,
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in the create action of your PostsController. Try the following:

```
def create
  @post = Post.create(params[:post])
  @km = current_user.kms.build(:post_id => @post.id)
  @km.save
end
```

You will still have to set a book_id on the Km, but it's not really clear to me how that will work because your post says it can `has_many :books, :through => :kms`, but a Km `belongs_to :book`. That doesn't make sense. What are you doing with the `book_ids` on the Post?

Comment: books and post was no problem, I just want generate `current_user.id` `km.user_id` when the `user` create a `post`.

Comment: The above will do that. current_user.kms.build() will create a new km with user_id == current_user.id. I only forgot to save the @km.

Comment: I have tried your solution, but user_id not filled, instead created a one new row, look screenshoot [this](http://i.cubeupload.com/RFtX2d.png)

Comment: How does your current_user.id evaluate? You could also simply do `Km.create(post_id: @post.id, user_id: current_user.id)` of course, but I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work. If current_user is an existing object with an ID, `current_user.kms.build` should create an empty Km with `user_id` set to `current_user.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want

```
@post = Post.create(params[:post])
current_user.kms.create(post_id: @post.id)
```

instead?

Comment: Thank's but not that, I want generate `current_user.id` to `km.user_id` when `user` create a `post`.